# Detect within trigger foreign key referential constraint

Tags: mysql, triggers, foreign-keys, constraints, referential-integrity

Within a trigger, how can I detect when a foreign key referential constraint prevented a delete from occurring?

My desire is to perform a delete statement on myTable, however, should a foreign key exist from another table to myTable, not to delete the row(s) from myTable, but modify a column in myTable for the record(s) where the delete was attempted.

Comment: Do you want to have a kind of `delete`-trigger on `MyTable` that reacts when you try to delete a row in `MyTable` and it fails, or do you mean you have a trigger on a different(!) table that, as part of its execution, tries to delete a row in `MyTable` and, when this fails, does something else? The latter is what I understood from your first sentence, but the rest of your question sound more like you mean the first case; since they have two different answers (the first case is not possible inside MySQL, the second one is), I wanted to make sure I understand it correctly.

Comment: @Solarflare  Your first sentence.  Delete a record from `MyTable`, and if it fails due to a constraint, update that record in `MyTable`.

Comment: That is unfortunately not possible. You can catch the exception in your app/script and handle it there. But if you want to delete more than one, none will be deleted if just one fails. A neat trick is to first update your rows with the new value, and then to use `delete ignore` to delete the rows (or vice versa). If the rows were deleted, it doesn't matter if they got the new value, and if they cannot be deleted, they have the new value now. `Ignore` prevents you from getting error (so you can delete more than one row). It can only be done from your app, and it will require 2 queries and time.

Comment: Thank you Solarflare,  At least now I know I should stop searching for such a solution (which would have been really nice!), and start coming up with others.  Also, thank you for your suggestions of other solutions.